# Where to secure php config.ini on my new Windows host?

Tags: php, iis, ini

I'm moving a php site I have to a new windows host.  With PHP we are told to put your db.ini files ABOVE the public_html folder to protect it from view.

Is there an equivalent practice for this with a Windows/IIS host?

Since the main site is served in the httpdocs folder, I tried putting it above that folder but that's clearly not allowed and got this error :
"File(../../../../mysecrets.ini) is not within the allowed path(s)"

Comment: For this error you can try to modify php.ini and to add the path for files.